# Adding image in Microsoft word dynamically

Tags: dynamic, ms-word

I want to insert image in Microsoft word dynamically.

I tried giving the link dynamically and it is displaying the link and not the image in Microsoft word.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: ['\t"image": "' +
          test.organization.organizationLogo +
          '",\n' +] it is in json string format. organization logo is the image url taken from database.

Comment: In the word file -> insert -> fields -> links->insert pictures. It is also displaying the image url and not the image.

Answer (score 0):

did this code still not work?

```vb
        'set your image link
    Dim imgUrlLink As String
    imgUrlLink = "https://dimage.ctext.org/g0015616/g0015616_1382.png"
    
    'Selection is where you want to insert to
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
        imgUrlLink, LinkToFile:=False, _
         SaveWithDocument:=True
```